# For a specific Role (or Profile or User) restrict access to certain Leads & Contacts based on field value

Tags: permissions, profile, roles, custom-profile

I am working on a Marketo-Salesforce sync.  Marketo accesses Salesforce via a Salesforce User named 'Marketo User'.  This User can have it's own Role, Profile, Permissions, etc. - it's sole purpose is to be the connection-point between Salesforce and Marketo.

We only want to sync certain records to Marketo, so we are evaluating our options to do this.  We want to avoid a custom record type for this.

We want to restrict access to certain Lead and Contact records based on a specific boolean field value, 'No Mkto Sync'.  When 'No Mkto Sync' is False, this User profile (or role?) should have full read/write privileges on the Lead or Contact record.  When this field is True, the Salesforce User should *not* be able to read/write that record.

Comment: does Marketo support selective sync'ing?

Comment: How are you determining which records to sync v not sync? Is it based on a set of criteria or manual?

Comment: Also, are your leads going through Marketo before Salesforce? By blocking read access, duplicates of your leads will be created by hiding them, causing Marketo to recreate them.

Comment: @crop1645 to our knowledge there is no way to configure selective sync rules other than a very standard one - if the Lead/Contact does not have an email address, do *not* sync to Marketo.  This can be achieved by contacting Marketo customer support

Comment: @MeighanRocksSF This is primarily to hold back some legacy Leads that are of varying degrees of quality, but also holding back a few segments of Lead and Contact records that are worked by partners and special business units.  Yeah the duplication issue is one that we discussed but we think that because the quantity of Leads that will have 'No Mkto Sync' = True will be relatively low volume, it will be manageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to setup Lead/Contact OWD as private, so that means only the owner of the records or someone higher in the role hierarchy will be able to read them.

*Setup > Security Controls > Sharing Settings*

Then add sharing rule based criteria, please check the following example where **Primary** will be your **No Mkto Sync**

Then select in step 4 to who you want to share this.

Hope that will help

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect walk-through - thank you!